# Swift 3 - "Clickwrap"-style agreement to Privacy Policy with UIAlertController

Tags: swift

I want to have my app display a UIAlertController to a new user that forces them to agree the Privacy Policy (or close the app). My Privacy Policy is hosted online. I am already capable of displaying *an* alert, but using buttons to link to the PP inevitably cause the alert to be dismissed after being pressed (after much searching, it seems this can not be changed without creating a custom controller).

I'd be happy to have the words "Privacy Policy" be a hyperlink in the alert, with a single "I Agree" button, but I've found that many people say this is counter to the almighty guidelines (despite my recollection that many iOS apps do this).

<s>How can I best</s> What are some ways to create a "[clickwrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_wrap)" agreement with the user using a UIAlertController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a UIAlertController. Don't use a link to something online. Include the text of the privacy policy in the app. Use a custom presented view controller as your modal dialog. It can be small and even look quite a lot like a system alert, but it will contain your text in a text view and the desired buttons, right there in the dialog.

(Instead of a text view, you *could* have a web view that loads the text from your web site, but this risks lack of connectivity at the key moment. Better to have the policy text built into the app.)

Comment: How might I present a view controller that looks like an alert (in the sense that it's smaller than the entire screen and pops over the current view controller)?

Comment: With a custom UIPresentationController and custom transition animation. It's easy. Here's a basic example to get you started: https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7